# Try catch can't catch the error

Tags: android

When I'm pressing register without typing anything in fields it does not show the alertbox from try catch block. Also when email is already in database, it should show the alertbox but it's not working.

```
public class activityregister extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText register_age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_age);
    final EditText register_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emails_reg);
    final EditText register_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
    final EditText register_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
    final Button reg_poga = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registacijas_poga);
    reg_poga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String name = register_name.getText().toString();
            final String email = register_email.getText().toString();
            final String age =  register_age.getText().toString();
            final String password = register_password.getText().toString();
           boolean pareizi = false;
          final Response.Listener <String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success"
                        );
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(activityregister.this, LoginRegister.class);
                            activityregister.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityregister.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Register is not completed!")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry the registration!",null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

               RegisterRequest registerRequestt= new RegisterRequest(name, email, age, password, responseListener);
               RequestQueue Que = Volley.newRequestQueue(activityregister.this);
               Que.add(registerRequestt);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What exception isn't being caught?

Comment: you can check the answer below with the explanation and solution for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **Exception** in place of **JSONException** in your catch block.

If you pass **Exception** in catch block , *then it will catch all kind of exceptions* , because Exception is the Parent class for all kind of Exceptions

right now you are using **JSONException** so it will only catch the error related to JSON.

use like this in your code

```
                   try{
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success"
                        );
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(activityregister.this, LoginRegister.class);
                            activityregister.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e){
                       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityregister.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Register is not completed!")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry the registration!",null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

as per your second requirement if email is empty etc. here i am giving your full code with correction

```
public class activityregister extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText register_age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_age);
    final EditText register_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emails_reg);
    final EditText register_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
    final EditText register_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
    final Button reg_poga = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registacijas_poga);
    reg_poga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String name = register_name.getText().toString();
            final String email = register_email.getText().toString();
            final String age =  register_age.getText().toString();
            final String password = register_password.getText().toString();
           boolean pareizi = false;

           if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
               // Here show alert or show toast , if email is empty
           } else {
          final Response.Listener <String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success"
                        );
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(activityregister.this, LoginRegister.class);
                            activityregister.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityregister.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Register is not completed!")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry the registration!",null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

               RegisterRequest registerRequestt= new RegisterRequest(name, email, age, password, responseListener);
               RequestQueue Que = Volley.newRequestQueue(activityregister.this);
               Que.add(registerRequestt);
        }

        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. But still when i'm pressing Register with empty fields it does not pop alert box. @Thunder

Comment: that case is different actually

Comment: Are you sure that this is necessary? Catching `Exception` usually isn't ideal.

Comment: yes thats fine if you are not sure what kind of exception can come

Comment: and if you want to show alert  if email field is emptyand pressed , so you need to put a check there on click event

Comment: Emm if i have php file that does not allow to save duplicated emails, how can i handle error like that? @Thunder

Comment: @Thunder THanks gonna try to fix my code with your codes help <3

Comment: yes , exactly and i added the full code with correction , which will make you able to check if email is empty

Comment: @Thunder Any idea why JSONException isnt working even tho i have the code in correct way. If i enter duplicated email it still does not pop up the alert box.

Comment: If email is empty and you need to handle that you need to take the code from my answer I added full code

Comment: I updated my answer with your full code + needed correction .

Comment: I added a condition check in your code when you clicking on the button so we are checking if email is empty then we are showing alert else we are hitting the API.